# Openstreetmap converting a url to an API request

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding

I was able to get the following URL, but trying to figure out which method it is calling from the OpenstreetMap public API. It is to grab the location of the US State of [`Arizona`](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/details.html?osmtype=R&osmid=162018&class=boundary), and its [`API Response in JSON`](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?osmtype=R&osmid=162018&class=boundary&addressdetails=1&hierarchy=0&group_hierarchy=1&polygon_geojson=1&format=json).

[image]

I am hoping there is a method for it at the API: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API. How can I grab this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read: https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Search/ for a complete documentation in accessing the Nominatim API.

Also please respect the usage policy found at: https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/